# Set background color for scope of searchbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

There is a default grey area for `UISearchbar` view. We can see the grey area while scroll down. I need to set `backgroundColor` for the grey area.

I have added `UISearchBar` to `UITableView` header. And there is a refresh control in the `UITableView`. Now the problem is when I pull down the refresh control it looks odd. Because refresh control takes **background of table view(white)** and **search view takes the default `backgroundColor`(grey)**.

If I set `backgroundColor` for `UISearchbar` it applies to only around `UISearchBar` not to the scope of `UISearchBar`. With that result I'm thinking whether the grey area is belongs to which view. I'm sure there is no extra view. I have set color to `tableview`, `refresh view`, `UISearchBar` and `self.view` but noting applies to the grey area.

Thanks,

Comment: [SearchItem setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: @KiritModi, As i mentioned if i set background for searchbar it applies only around the view not to scope.

Comment: @All, the below line fixed my problem, but no idea how :)             [tableview setBackgroundView:[UIImageView new]];

Comment: UIView also does the trick in place of UIImageView. Basically set a background view which is colorless so it won't affect other views.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `view` inside the `searchbar` where the grey area is placed. name it as `searchBarView` or something that u like.

```
self.scrollView.searchBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourcolor];
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for reply! I haven't add any scrollview, scroll i meant default tableview scroll.

Comment: add another view inside, and position it with CGRect dynamically or put it statically via storyboard and do the above.
And if it solved ur issue please tick beside the answer :)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
searchbar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27, -5, 143, 44)];
        searchbar.tag = indexPath.row+1;
        searchbar.delegate = self;
        searchbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        if (IS_IOS_7) {
            [searchbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }else{
            [[ [searchbar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a **transparent** `scope bar` add a 1Pixel PNG with Alpha to the scope bar.

Otherwise stays white, even with transparent searchBar background.

[image: btw. this png is named alpha]

[image: the transparent sprachbar and scopeBar]